# Kafka monitoring in Azure

Tags: azure, apache-kafka, azure-application-insights, azure-monitoring

We are hosting Confluent Platform services(broker, zookeeper, schema-registry etc.) in Azure VMs. What is the best option to scrape metrics from these and visualize in Azure monitor or application insights?
I am thinking to scrape JMX metrics and visualize in azure monitor/app insights. Monitoring will include things like health status, message flow in topics, produce/consume rate, VM health etc.

What are some good options to implement this? Any better ideas?

PS- I only want to use Azure native services for monitoring/dashboards.

Answer (score 0):

You can add java agents by exporting the environment variable `KAFKA_OPTS`. Through that, you can add any additional JVM monitoring

Azure docs - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/java-in-process-agent